# Handling JSON in Python 3.7

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, opencorporates

I am using Python 3.7 and I am trying to handle some JSON data that I receive back from a website. A sample of the JSON response is below but it can vary in length. In essence, it returns details about 'officers' and in the example below, there is data for two officers. This is using the [OpenCorporates](https://api.opencorporates.com/documentation/API-Reference) API

```
{"api_version":"0.4","results":{"page":1,"per_page":30,"total_pages":1,"total_count":2,"officers":[{"officer":{"id":212927580,"uid":null,"name":"NEIL KIDMAN","jurisdiction_code":"gb","position":"director","retrieved_at":"2015-12-04T00:00:00+00:00","opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/officers/212927580","start_date":"2015-01-28","end_date":null,"occupation":"SERVICE MANAGER","current_status":null,"inactive":false,"company":{"name":"GRSS LIMITED","jurisdiction_code":"gb","company_number":"09411531","opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/gb/09411531"}}},{"officer":{"id":190031476,"uid":null,"name":"NEIL KIDMAN","jurisdiction_code":"gb","position":"director","retrieved_at":"2015-12-04T00:00:00+00:00","opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/officers/190031476","start_date":"2002-05-17","end_date":null,"occupation":"COMPANY DIRECTOR","current_status":null,"inactive":false,"company":{"name":"GILBERT ROAD SERVICE STATION LIMITED","jurisdiction_code":"gb","company_number":"04441363","opencorporates_url":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/gb/04441363"}}}]}}
```

My code so far is:-

```
response = requests.get(url) 
response.raise_for_status() 
jsonResponse = response.json() 
officerDetails = jsonResponse['results']['officers']
```

This works well but my ultimate goal is to create variables and write them to a .csv. So I'd like to write something like:-

```
name = jsonResponse['results']['officers']['name']
position = jsonResponse['results']['officers']['name']
companyName = jsonResponse['results']['officers']['company']['name']
```

Any suggestions how I could do this? As said, I'd like to loop through each 'officer' in the JSON response and then capture these values and write to a .csv (I will tackle the .csv part once I have them assigned to the variables)

Comment: `officers` is a list, you should be able to use a `for .. in` loop to iterate over all officers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
officers = jsonResponse['results']['officers']

res = []
for officer in officers:
    data = {}
    data['name'] = officer['officer']['name']
    data['position'] = officer['officer']['position']
    data['company_name'] = officer['officer']['company']['name']
    res.append(data)
```

You can then go ahead to write `res`, which is a `list of objects` to a csv file.